# If z be any complex number and if $z^2 + az + b = 0$ has two roots both of which has unit modulus, then prove that $|a| \leq 2$, and $|b| = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $z$ be any complex number and if $z^2 + az + b = 0$ has two roots both of which has unit modulus, then prove that $|a| \leq 2, |b| = 1$

I'm using the quadratic equation formula to find the roots and then equating it's modulus to $1$ but I don't understand how to approach after that to prove the given result.

Comment: Hint: what is the relation between a,b and the roots of the equation?

Comment: @SorinTirc umm, do you mean using the formula for sum of roots and product of roots of a quadratic equation?

Comment: Yup, that's right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Viète's formulas are also valid for complex numbers. Since both roots are of unit modulus, their product $b$ also has unit modulus, while their sum $-a$ has modulus at most 2 by the triangle inequality, so $|a|\le2$.